# Android emulator just sits there?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Whenever I try to run my Android app, the emulator just sits there on this screen: 
[image: Are you kidding me.]

RAM is set to 1024MB. Any idea why this is happening/how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wait 2 or 3 minutes.

.........................

Comment: It does that for about 35 minutes before I snap and just exit out of it.

Comment: then I'd suggest you to post additional details such as the operative system and whatever else pops to your mind.
Also if nobody answers you here, you may try to contact some Android SDK developer directly, I saw some of them hanging out on twitter :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to launch it from **adb command**

```
emulator -avd <name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without any output from the console. Are you running it from Eclipse? If so, try running from command line.

Also, you could try creating another device configuration and running that.

If that doesn't work. Try downloading the app again.

Lastly, here are some similar threads, check these out:
[Android emulator not starting at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214389/android-emulator-not-starting-at-all)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082063/android-emulator-freezes

http://www.anddev.org/the_emulator_doesnt_start-t36.html

Answer (score 0):

Just check your pc/laptop is restartable. 
I too had the same problem. Nothing worked. But I checked my laptop is restartable after deleting **.android** folder in user home 
`(c:\users\androidStuckUser\.android)` . Worked for me