# Virtual Device i.e emulator is not able to start android app?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator

I have download and install `adt-bundle-windows-x86` successfully on my machine

But when I try to run and execute any android app ,

`NewDevice` i.e `emulator` is not going to show anything , it is going to stuck at loading stage why is it so?

I tried following also:

```
Right click the root of your Android Project, go to "Run As" then go to "Run Configurations..." locate the "Android Application" node in the tree at the left, then select your project and go to the "Target" tab on the right side of the window look down for the "Additional Emulator Command Line Options" field (sometimes you'll need to make the window larger) and finally paste "-partition-size 1024" there. Click Apply and then Run to use your emulator.
```

set preference also.
[image]
please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: Please set the preference in eclipse->windows->preference->to android sdk path

Comment: what should i set in preference ? please guide in detail i'm newbie thanks

Comment: You should go to Android tab ->set the path of your android sdk in your system.

Comment: I did that also.. uploaded img please tell me what is wrong .. thanks

Comment: Use this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214389/android-emulator-not-starting-at-all

Comment: It is loading very very slow any reason?