# Android emulator doesn't start from the manager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

When I try to run android emulator from android studio, I see this in android studio:

[image]

it fills up and then nothing happens.

I saw these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214389/android-emulator-not-starting-at-all), but they're old and the command `emulator` isn't even recognized on my pc.

When I go to `C:\Android\sdk\tools` and press `emulator.exe` nothing happens as well.

I also tried to make a new virtual device with the manager but it also didn't work.

It worked two days ago just fine.

I'm on win 10.

What else can I try? Could it be because the path `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools` has a space on my username? (what's instead of `<user>` I mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows OS:

Go to run and type cmd to open command prompt.
Now move to the location where adb is located.

```
C:/> cd /Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools/
```

To stop adb, run:

```
C:/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools/> adb kill-server
```

To start adb:

```
C:/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools/> adb start-server
```

Comment: I tried that in both `C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools` and `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools` and both didn't help.

Comment: Can you write logcat?

Comment: Any specific command to add to it? I'm just getting `- waiting for device -`